Windows 11 machine not sleeping / display not sleeping either
I have been attempting to troubleshoot an issue that has plagued me ever since reformatting my machine to Win11. Ever since, Win11 will not sleep properly nor will it put my display to sleep either.
At first I thought it had to do with a couple of new programs I'm using - SignalRGB for RGB lighting control and Lively Wallpaper for live wallpaper.
So I started to investigate. I did the CMD powercfg /requests and noticed that most of the time, the only thing that was causing the machine not to sleep was "[DRIVER] Legacy Kernel Caller" under SYSTEM. So I went to work. I did the powercfg /requestsoverride and overrid that, but it didn't help. I also went about following a few sites to see if anything could help. The sites in question are:
Legacy Kernel Caller preventing sleep mode
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-wont-sleep-legacy-kernel-caller-in/48305164-e19e-468a-9560-9bf05cbe63ef
But it seemed like nothing was really working.
I started to unplug devices one by one to see if anything stuck out. What stuck out was that my SPEAKERS with a 3.5MM jack plugged into my MB was causing the issue. After it was unplugged, my display went to sleep. If I plugged it back in, my display instantly turned back on.
With that determined, I went to Device Manager and uninstalled my Speakers option and it removed the request as well. However, of course, after a reboot it came back.
I went to my MB manufacturer and downloaded the RealTek firmware and drivers to update, however it seems to have made things Worse.
Now, as seen in the screen shot above actually, the SPDIF option is there (it wasn't beforehand). Even after uninstalling the RealTek drivers (since I noticed the drivers were USB-only?), that SPDIF option still persists.
But here's the odd thing now. Now, powercfg /requests shows a USB Audio 2.0 item in there and it will NOT go away, even when nothing is playing audio at all that I can hear. https://imgur.com/4w4nBpU
I found yet another site that mentioned to attempt to add more powercfg overrides, which doesn't seem to help at all. https://imgur.com/cuaKsqA
Any suggestions on how I can get this thing back to normal where it sleeps properly? And to potentially even fix my sound options from before I installed that RealTek driver, even though I don't even have them installed anymore?
I don't remember having this issue at all in Win10.
Thank you!

Does you PC meet Win 11 requirements, or did you use a work-around to install that OS?

@John, apologies if it's not completely focused. I don't seem to see a power manager driver (ROG STRIX B650-A GAMING WIFI). I will reset the basic balanced plan to default, though. BIOS is completely updated to the latest version.

@DrMoishePippik, no, it was installed properly. I never utilized Win11 as I wasn't really interested. Was always on Win10, which had no issue with sleeping the computer or display.
